# How to avoid nginx cache critical errors with message "cache file x has too long header"?

Tags: nginx, caching

Running nginx 1.18.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.6, I have a recurring critical error happening when random resources are requested.

All these requests are through nginx proxy_cache. Example of one of these error messages:

`[crit] 316179#316179: *52436 cache file "/var/cache/nginx/site/e/ad/7b00d93695d5b46103916cb82d5a0ade" has too long header, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Directives I have tried adjusting:

- proxy_buffer_size;
- proxy_buffers;
- proxy_busy_buffers_size;
- large_client_header_buffers

However, IF one of these would be correct in trying to fix the issue I'm not sure how to calculate the needed amount and from what datapoint. The size of http headers to fetch a cached file? No clue.

First step to solving it would be to understand when and where this is happening. It is seemingly intermittent in nature.
For a given cached resource where this critical error happens, it is possible to directly afterwards request the url successfully. And I have not seen first hand what happens to a request that triggers the critical error. Perhaps it receives a 500 error?

Answer (score 0):

Found a [nginx forum thread discussing the same issue](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,271382,271382#msg-271382).

[One solution suggested](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,271382,271383#msg-271383) increasing `proxy_buffer_size`, but if the cached file is already smaller than your buffer size,

it could be just some corrupt file because it was generated with an older version of nginx and now you're trying to serve it with a newer version.

See https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,271382,271400#msg-271400

I was having this issue with just *one* specific cached file, so I just deleted it and will let nginx cache it again and that might solve the issue.